# Unexpected behaviour of onChildAdded stream in firebase_database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I've recently started learning Flutter and the FlutterFire plugins. Yesterday I was working with the
firebase_database plugin which allows adding Firebase Realtime Database to Flutter. While trying out a
simple read on the database I noticed some strange behavior in one of the Streams provided by firebase_database which is onChildAdded.

So my problem is that when I use the onChildAdded stream with a StreamBuilder it only returns a single latest child. When I used to work with Firebase Database in Java the onChildAdded method was called for each child of a DatabaseReference instead of just the latest child. (Assuming that onChildAdded provides the same behavior in both Java and Dart)

I should also mention that when I use the onValue stream everything works fine and I get all the children of my DatabaseReference.

This is how my Firebase Database looks:

[image: This is how my Firebase Database looks]

Code using onChildAdded

```
Widget _getBody(BuildContext context) {
    final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: databaseRef.child("notes").child('android').onChildAdded,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> notes = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;

          notes.forEach(
              (key, value) {
                print(notes[key]);
              }
          );
        }
        return Container(); //Just a blank widget because builder has to return a widget
      },
    );
  }
```

Output for onChildAdded:
[image: Output for onChildAdded]

Code using onValue

```
Widget _getBody(BuildContext context) {
    final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: databaseRef.child("notes").child('android').onValue,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<dynamic> notes = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;

          notes.forEach(
              (item) {
                print("$item \n");
              }
          );
        }
      return Container(); //Just a placeholder because builder has to return a widget
    },
  );
}
```

Output for onValue:

[image: Output for onValue]

So I was hoping for a way where it's possible to get all the children using the onChildAdded stream. Any help is appreciated!